Component renders previous state
I'm running Expo 50 with react-native 0.73.4 and react-navigation 6.
In the following code, the components are not added after the content has been fetched from the API.
If I run a refresh using the refresh control, the previous state is shown. This happens elsewhere too, but I am using the same sort of pattern throughout the app.
const ChecklistScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
    const [checklists, setChecklists] = useState([]);
    const [isRefreshing, setIsRefreshing] = useState(false);

    const fetchChecklists = async () => {
        setIsRefreshing(true);

        setChecklists(await checklistRepository.getChecklists())
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchChecklists();
    }, []);

    return (
        <ScrollView refreshControl={
            <RefreshControl refreshing={! isRefreshing} onRefresh={fetchChecklists}
        }>
            { checklists.map((checklist) => {
                <Text>{checklist.name}</Text>
            }) }
        </ScrollView>
    );
};

It is like my state is always one behind what I'm expecting.

You are probably confused by the two renders cause by the two setStates. The renders triggered by the two setStates cannot be batched in this situation.
This is because the second one is supposed to run after a promise completion. The second setState will be added to the execution stack only when the promise has been fulfilled. Till then react has already triggered the first render and the callstack is empty. The second setState would be running much later. Hence the two cannot be batched together.
This is the same as doing the below code:
const promise = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(1);
    }, 6000);
  });
};

function App() {
  const [simple, setSimple] = useState(0);

  const [awaited, setAwaited] = useState(0);

  const onClick = async () => {
    setSimple((x) => x + 1);
    const newVal = await promise();
    setAwaited(newVal);
    console.log("after");
  };

  console.log("render", simple, awaited);
  return (
    <>
      <p>{simple}</p>

      <p>{awaited}</p>

      <button onClick={onClick}>Test</button>
    </>
  );
}


On clicking the button, render output will be like the below:
render 1 0
after
render 1 1



const { Fragment, useState } = React;

const promise = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(1);
    }, 6000);
  });
};

function App() {
  const [simple, setSimple] = useState(0);
  const [awaited, setAwaited] = useState(0);

  const onClick = () => {
    setSimple((x) => x + 1);
    promise().then((newVal) => {
      setAwaited(newVal);
      console.log("after");
    });
  };

  console.log("render", simple, awaited);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <p>{simple}</p>
      <p>{awaited}</p>
      <button onClick={onClick}>Test</button>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>



Here is the github issue where it is documented
